# Prevent IntelliJ from removing newlines around single statement methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes IntelliJ will take single statement methods and put them on the same line, as seen here:

[image]

If I click either bracket it will turn back into:

[image]

This question isn't a debate for which of the two is *better* - I want to know how to turn this off. I combed through IntelliJ preferences and couldn't seem to find anything, and searching both here and Google didn't bring up what I wanted.

Comment: If it's the same behavior I'm thinking of, it doesn't actually remove the newlines.  It just collapses the code in the editor and puts a little '+' in the margin.  If that's what you're seeing, that may help you find the option to turn it off.  I think you can search options for keywords, so try searching for "collapse".

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Well yeah it doesn't physically remove them because clicking either bracket re-expands. I'll clarify in my question - but for what you said I want to keep the ability to collapse on the margin using the `+`/`-`, just not _this_ - which does it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think these options are responsible for this:
[image]

Comment: Oh, nice.  There's a lot of annoying stuff that I didn't realize could be switched off.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yup!

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about code reformatting putting the extra newlines into your code, then it's the "Simple methods in one line" option you want to check in Editor/Code Style/Scala/Wrapping and Braces:
[image]

Comment: Note the tag: this is [tag:java].

Comment: ah, I didn't notice that.